# accurate cutting of video (+ audio) with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4, codec

I want my website to allow users to accurately create their own clips from a source video I provide.

I have a source video file that I first want to convert to something suitable for a website:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'source.mkv': 
Duration: 00:28:18.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10183 kb/s 
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
```

I use ffmpeg to convert it like so:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -vf scale="960:-1" source.mp4
```

Watching this video back it is good enough quality and small enough file size for my needs, and loads/plays on my website.

I have a webpage that lets users select a start and endpoint on this video - and create a clip.  Here's an example of the ffmpeg command that I use for that:

```
-ss 577.920 -i source.mp4 -t 011.980 -codec:v copy -codec:a copy -vf scale="960:-1" clip1.mp4
```

The problem is the clip is not always time-accurate enough.  Usually the audio is accurate enough but the video stops half a second early or something.

Is there any way to make this accurate and in-sync to say, 0.2 of a second?

EDIT:
Adding `-force_key_frames 00:00:00.2` didn't help.

EDIT:
I changed the clipping to use `-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental` instead of `-codec:v copy -codec:a copy` with good (ish) results.

The file can play externally without issue - but when I load it into my html5 video element and play it - the last part of the video (audio is fine) freezes.  The last part that freezes is less than a second long.

Should I try it with another video encoder?  What is the best alternative for libx264?  Bearing in mind I will probably want this to be on a public website.

But hang on doesn't the fact that it plays accurately without issue with a player like MPC or Windows Media Player suggest that it is a problem with either Google Chrome or the HTML video element?  Or am I using an unsupported encoding or something?

Comment: This might have to do with the timing of key frames.  In any case, this should be moved to SuperUser.com.

Comment: Hi, ffmpeg can't cut the video at any point, it only can cut on keyframes; for this reason audio is almost precise, while video isn't.

Comment: Can I move it myself?  I will try adding key frames to the source file with -force_key_frames 00:00:00.2

Answer (score 9):

The behavior of `-ss` changes depending if it used as an input or output option, and is often slower but can be more accurate when used as an output option. See the answer to [ffmpeg converts video from specified time period slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208967/1109017) for more details and examples.

To change output quality for `source.mp4` use the `-crf` option with a value between 18-28 (23 is default). See the CRF section of the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for examples.

Your trimming command can be simplified:

```
ffmpeg -ss 577.92 -i source.mp4 -ss 0 -t 11.98 -c copy -map 0 clip1.mp4
```

I replaced `-codec:v copy -codec:a copy` with `-c copy -map 0`. This will copy all streams instead of just the first video and audio streams--although the input only has two streams due to your previous command. Since you can not scale without re-encoding, therefore being mutually exclusive with `-codec:v copy`, and since your input is already scaled to the set size I removed the filter options.

If it is still not accurate enough then try:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 577.92 -t 11.98 -c copy -map 0 clip1.mp4
```

It will be slower, but probably more accurate. See the links in the answer in the first link I provided for a description of the differences of these two examples.

Lastly, you should run `source.mp4` through `qt-faststart` (located in the tools directory in ffmpeg source), or use the `-movflags faststart` option. This will relocate some data to the beginning of the file so it can begin playback before it is completely downloaded.

Comment: +1 for the tips but I tried ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 577.92 -t 011.980 -c copy -map 0 clip1.mp4 but the first part (almost a second) and last part (maybe quarter of a second) of the video is missed, audio is fine though.

Comment: @PeteOakey Have you tried cutting without bitstream copy, but actual re-encoding?

Comment: Tried it without bitstream copy - results appended to my question.

Comment: Using `-ss` as output option instead of input option fixed my problem: the first video frame was around 1s in the output video, with only audio before that (also confirmed by `ffprobe -show_frames`). Moving `-ss` after `-i` made it output audio and video frames starting at frame 0.